# Connecting an existing project to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I have files that make up a project in TFS. They are not in a VS project, they are just loose files. I pull them from source control to my machine and then created a new project in the root of the files. I've included all the files in the project. My question is how do I connect my project to the existing files in source control? Right now there are no bindings inside my newly created project.

Comment: You should probably post this on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, add your project to source control, then go to Solution Explorer, right-click and choose Add | Existing Item, then browse to the files you want to add.

Notice that you have the option to add the file as a link.  The way that works is that if you add the file then VS moves the file to the project's location, thus creating a second copy of the file - which is probably not what you want.  If you add the file as a link then the file remains in its location and is not moved.

[image: add existing files]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The files are already in source control. What I am trying to do is create a project in Visual Studio, add the files pulled from source control to the project and then bind the project to source control. All the files are already in source control they are just not part of a project.

Comment: Yes, didn't read your question properly the first time.  Have edited the answer, hope that helps.